# Database updation issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite

I am trying to update my database with some values using following code. But the values are not updated and it stored null to the same.

```
int NoOfItem = [str_NoOfitems integerValue];
int FurnitureId = [str_FurnitueId integerValue];
NSLog(@"FurnitureId %@", str_FurnitueId);
@try {
    if (sqlite3_open([[SQLDataFile getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        if(updateStmt == nil) 
        {
            NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE FurnitureSelected Set  NoOfItem = ? Where FurnitureId = %d" ,    FurnitureId];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"erroe while creating Update statement  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database) );

            }               
        }

//      sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [str_NoOfitems UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, NoOfItem);
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



    }

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception occured while Updating datbase for FurnitureSelected %@", [e description]);
}
@finally
{
    [SQLDataFile finalizeStatements];
}
```

In above code , no of the values are null  still the database is storing null values after update. In insert it works perfect.

The Insert code is like (this is performed before update)

+(void)InsertFurnitureValues:(NSString *)str_FurnitureId:(NSString *)str_NoOfItems:(NSString *)str_RoomId
{

```
int noOfItem = [str_NoOfItems integerValue];
int FId = [str_FurnitureId integerValue];
@try 
{

    if (sqlite3_open([[SQLDataFile getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        if(addStmt == nil) 
        {
            const char *sql = "insert into FurnitureSelected(AutoId,RoomId, FurnitureId, NoOfItem) Values(?,?, ?,?)";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 3, FId);//sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [str_RoomId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [str_RoomId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 4, noOfItem);//(addStmt, 4, [str_NoOfItems UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);

    }

}
@catch (NSException * e) 
{
    NSLog(@"Exception occure %@" , [e description]);
}
@finally 
{
    [SQLDataFile finalizeStatements];
}
```

}

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling sqlite3_finalize on your prepared statement.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but got the solution - the error was -  sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, NoOfItem); , we need to keep 1 instead 3 if we are going to update only 1 value. that was the issue.